# Nav bar is not lining up properly

Tags: html, css

So i'm working on a nav bar which should be aligned horizontally, but it won't. If i try to use

```
display: inline-block;
```

and then

```
float: left;
```

the navbar collides with the rest of my divisions

Here's my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/0p287vmb/

Comment: Since you're using `float: left;` the nav aligns itself to the left edge of the parent, but so does the rest of the content, because the nav-bar is no longer part of the normal page flow, when using float. Do you want the nav-bar to be to the left of the header or underneath it, with the content being pushed to the center?

Comment: just use `display: initial` on `<a>` also remove `display: inline-block` on hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
nav
a {
    font-family: Impact;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav
a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I removed the commas because with commas it translates to nav & a. In your case removing it solves the problem also it overwrote the width of the nav that's why it doesn't seem to take up the whole width.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the width from nav tag.

```css
* {
   font-family: Verdana;
   font-size: 14px;
   margin: 0;
}

p {
   padding 20px;
}

#wrapper {
   width: 900px;
   background-color: #ff3333;
   margin: auto;
}

header {
   background-color: #00c9fd;
   width: 900px;
}

nav {
   background-color: #cccccc;
   width: 900px;
}

a {
   font-family: Impact;
   font-size: 15px;
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 50px;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 5px 10px;
   float: left;
}

nav,
a:hover {
   background-color: white;
   display: inline-block;
}

#bigimage {
   width: 900px;
}

#bigimage,
p {
   color: #00c9fd;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 12px;
}

main {
   width: 900px;
}

article {
   background-color: #cccccc;
   width: 900px;
}

#contact {
   background-color: #cccccc;
   width: 900px;
}

footer {
   background-color: #00c9fd;
   width: 900px;
}

header,
h1 {
   padding: 20px 0px 5px 0px;
   color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   font-size: 30px;
   font-family: Impact;
   text-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_new.css">
</head>

<body>
   <div id="wrapper">
      <header>
     <h1>SUPERCOMPUTERS</h1>
      </header>
   <nav>
   <a href="http://www.pbruinaars.ictlaurens.nl/opdrachtje/new.html">Home</a>
   <a href="http://www.pbruinaars.ictlaurens.nl/opdrachtje/new.html">Meer informatie</a>
   <a href="http://www.pbruinaars.ictlaurens.nl/opdrachtje/new.html">Tijdlijn</a>
   </nav>
  <div id="bigimage">
   <img src="images/titanadfacomputer.jpg" alt="Titan 2 Supercomputer" width="900">
   <p>
    <b>Lorem</b> <br> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mollis turpis sit amet blandit malesuada. Praesent at lacus rutrum, auctor justo sed, consectetur massa. Cras gravida vehicula vulputate. Ut magna odio, mollis non dolor
    at, dignissim faucibus eros.
   </p>
  </div>
  <main>
   <article>hoi1</article>
   <article>hoi2</article>
   <article>hoi3</article>
  </main>
  <div id="contact">hoi4</div>
  <footer>hoi5</footer>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are overriding the width of the navbar in

```
nav,
a {
    ...
    width: 200px;
    ...
}
```

and the display block here:

```
nav,
a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Just move the navbar styling after nav,a:hover ..., and remove nav from the same place because you are also ovveriding the background color of the nav.

Also, on the last line it should be font-weight not text-weight.

```css
   * {
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin: 0;
}

p {
 padding 20px;
}

#wrapper {
 width: 900px;
 background-color: #ff3333;
 margin: auto;
}

header {
 background-color: #00c9fd;
 width: 900px;
}



nav,
a {
 font-family: Impact;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 50px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 float: left;
}

a:hover {
 background-color: white;
 display: inline-block;
}

nav {
 background-color: #cccccc;
 width: 900px;
}


#bigimage {
 width: 900px;
}

#bigimage,
p {
 color: #00c9fd;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 12px;
}

main {
 width: 900px;
}

article {
 background-color: #cccccc;
 width: 900px;
}

#contact {
 background-color: #cccccc;
 width: 900px;
}

footer {
 background-color: #00c9fd;
 width: 900px;
}

header,
h1 {
 padding: 20px 0px 5px 0px;
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 font-size: 30px;
 font-family: Impact;
 text-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper">
  <header>
   <h1>SUPERCOMPUTERS</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
   <a href="http://www.pbruinaars.ictlaurens.nl/opdrachtje/new.html">Home</a>
   <a href="http://www.pbruinaars.ictlaurens.nl/opdrachtje/new.html">Meer informatie</a>
   <a href="http://www.pbruinaars.ictlaurens.nl/opdrachtje/new.html">Tijdlijn</a>
  </nav>
  <div id="bigimage">
   <img src="images/titanadfacomputer.jpg" alt="Titan 2 Supercomputer" width="900">
   <p>
    <b>Lorem</b> <br> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mollis turpis sit amet blandit malesuada. Praesent at lacus rutrum, auctor justo sed, consectetur massa. Cras gravida vehicula vulputate. Ut magna odio, mollis non dolor
    at, dignissim faucibus eros.
   </p>
  </div>
  <main>
   <article>hoi1</article>
   <article>hoi2</article>
   <article>hoi3</article>
  </main>
  <div id="contact">hoi4</div>
  <footer>hoi5</footer>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector was wrong. You wrote `nav, a` which would mean to apply those styles to both `nav` and `a` elements. Infact you needed `nav a` which means to only apply those styles to `a` elements that are children of `nav` elements.

```
nav a {
  font-family: Impact;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
}
```